# How to display enemy distance as a warning?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Visualization of the problem]

I'm developing a game in Unity where enemies (birds) spawn at a distance from the player. However, sometimes these enemies spawn outside the camera view, which can surprise the player and make it difficult for them to anticipate threats. To address this issue, I want to implement a system that displays a warning to the player indicating the distance and direction of the enemy.

Here's what I want to achieve:

When a bird spawns at a distance from the player, I want to calculate a straight line between the player and the bird, and determine the point where this line intersects with the screen edge or camera view edge.

At this intersection point, I want to display the distance between the player and the bird on screen with a warning sign.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to implement this system in Unity? I would greatly appreciate any insights or code examples on how to achieve this functionality effectively.

Here is what I put together so far, but it isn't working as intended.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class BirdDistance : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player1;
    public Camera mainCamera;

    private void Start()
    {
        player1 = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        // Calculate direction vector from player to bird
        Vector3 directionToPlayer = (player1.position - transform.position).normalized;

        // Calculate intersection point with screen edge
        Vector3 intersectionPoint = CalculateIntersectionPoint(directionToPlayer);

        // Convert intersection point to screen space
        Vector3 screenIntersectionPoint = mainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(intersectionPoint);

        // Check if intersection point is within screen bounds
        if (IsPointWithinScreenBounds(screenIntersectionPoint))
        {
            // Calculate distance between player and bird
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(player1.position, transform.position);

            // Display distance and direction information on the screen
            GUI.Label(new Rect(screenIntersectionPoint.x, Screen.height - screenIntersectionPoint.y, 200, 50),
                      "Bird approaching from " + GetDirectionFromScreenPoint(screenIntersectionPoint) + "\nDistance: " + distance.ToString("F2"));
        }
    }

    private Vector3 CalculateIntersectionPoint(Vector3 direction)
    {
        // Calculate intersection point with screen edge
        float t = 100f; // Adjust this value as needed
        Vector3 intersectionPoint = transform.position + direction * t;
        return intersectionPoint;
    }

    private bool IsPointWithinScreenBounds(Vector3 point)
    {
        // Check if the point is within the screen bounds
        return point.x >= 0 && point.x <= Screen.width && point.y >= 0 && point.y <= Screen.height;
    }

    private string GetDirectionFromScreenPoint(Vector3 screenPoint)
    {
        // Determine the direction from the screen point
        float screenWidth = Screen.width;
        float screenHeight = Screen.height;

        if (screenPoint.x <= 0)
        {
            return "left";
        }
        else if (screenPoint.x >= screenWidth)
        {
            return "right";
        }
        else if (screenPoint.y <= 0)
        {
            return "bottom";
        }
        else
        {
            return "top";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) or [linecast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Linecast.html) between your player and the bird.

These methods have an output parameter of the type [RaycastHit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html) which can be used to get information on where the ray intersects with the edge.

If you have colliders other than the screen edge between the player and bird, you may need a [LayerMask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html).

If you want a more detailed answer or specific guidelines, please provide snippets of the relevant code.